# Best way to load image from list python script

Tags: python

For some reason i have append images , now i want load all image by step.

```
image_path  = C:
image_list= []
for fn in os.listdir(image_path):
    image_list.append(fn)
    ###first_image = bpy.data.images.load(image_list[0])  <----?
    ###second_image =  bpy.data.images.load(image_list[1])   <----?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to batch load a list of images in a folder:

```
import bpy
from os.path import join, isfile
from os import listdir

imageObjects = []
imagePath = '/users/you/yourImagePath'
imgFiles  = [
    join( imagePath, fn )                    # Create full paths to images
    for fn in listdir( imagePath )           # For each item in the image folder
    if isfile( join( imagePath, fn ) )       # If the item is indeed a file
    and fn.lower().endswith(('.png','.jpg')) # Which ends with an image suffix (can add more types here if needed)
]

# Load entire list of images
for imgFile in imgFiles:
    # Add to image object list to use later
    imageObjects.append( bpy.data.images.load( imgFile ) ) 

# Load a specific index from the list (5th in the list in this example)
imgObj = bpy.data.images.load( imgFiles[4] )
```

Comment: ty but i have to load not full image list because have  some variable by controlling the loading , i have to know the way by load single image from list. for example the first image of the list and in the second step , load second image.

Comment: @Andrea see edit and LMK if this is what you meant

Comment: Sorry @TLousky in the first time i put name of node with diffuse = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeTexImage')
diffuse.location = (-600,550)
diffuse.name =  imgFiles[0]  now name is all path of image.. in the first time is only image name. an idea?

Comment: try to replace the imports from os.path and add `basename`. Like this:  `from os.path import join, isfile, basename`. Then use it in the diffuse.name: `diffuse.name = basename(imgFiles[0])`. Basename extracts the filename from a full path.

Comment: Work very fine is very usefull, ty